# animating elements a random negative or positive amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, random

I'm trying to use math.random to animate the characters of these words by a random amount with math.random and it isn't working. 
Is it a problem with my math [DEMO](https://jsbin.com/cixavotifu/edit?html,js,output)

```
 $('.reverse_button').on('click', function(){

    var chars = $('.reverse_body').blast({
        delimiter: 'character'
    });
             var moveup=parseInt((Math.random()* document.body.clientHeight) - document.body.clientHeight);
         var moveleft=parseInt((Math.random()* document.body.clientWidth) - document.body.clientWidth);
    chars.each(function(idx,obj) {


         $(obj).animate({
            left: moveleft,
            top: moveup
            });
         });
        });
```

This is what I'm trying to get work first. There is an error here.

```
 $('.reverse_button').on('click', function(){

    var chars = $('.reverse_body').blast({
        delimiter: 'character'
    });

    chars.each(function() {

        $(this).animate({
           left: 100,
           top: 100
           }, 500);
        });
       });
```

Comment: simplify your code. `$('.reverse_body').animate({left: -10, top: -10});` would rule out any math related problems if it still didn't work.

Comment: my problem is getting the random animation amount to work. If i assigned -10 value it wouldn't be random, and it wouldn't animate each seperate character

Comment: Right, but does it work when you make it not random. this is part of debugging, confirming that the problem has to do with randomization and not the animation/css itself. I don't know what .blast does, but you can't set the left and top values of an inline positioned element and expect it to do something.

Comment: Also, you're only generating the random values once, and then using the same random values for each character, so I think your logic is a bit flawed in that regard.

Comment: no it doesn't work and i can't figure out why, i've been at it for two hours

Comment: Edited post with code that has the problem

Comment: is there an error, or does it just not work. My guess is this is a CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

@KevinB

I needed to give the effected element a position of relative. Here is the working code and demo.

```
 $('.reverse_button').on('click', function(){

    var chars = $('.reverse_body').blast({
        delimiter: 'character'
    });

    chars.each(function() {
                var moveup=parseInt((Math.random()* document.body.clientHeight) - document.body.clientHeight);
                 var moveleft=parseInt((Math.random()* document.body.clientWidth) - document.body.clientWidth);
        $(this).css({
            position: 'relative',
            left: 0
        })
        .animate({
           left: moveleft,
           top: moveup
       }, 1500);
        });
       });
```

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/sosixofuri/edit?html,js,output)

However it still isn't animating a negative amount, anyone know a formula to create a random negative number?